# .xdo and .xdm files missing in OBIEE 12c

Tags: obiee, bi-publisher

I created a report in OBIEE12c. But I dint find and .xdo, .xdm, xdo.cfg .... file in any of the folders.  In OBIEE 11g they use to be there in some repository directory. Where and how OBIEE 12c stores catalog objects/repositories.

Comment: Can you explain why you want this information, as it is probably going to help frame the answer. XDO etc are BI Publisher objects. OBIEE itself continues to use the Presentation Catalog for storing metadata exactly as it did in 11g.

Comment: We have a product which has some reports created in BIP 11g. During installation of our product we will copy these .xdo, .xdm, ... files to BIP 11g directory structure. Now we have to upgrade to BIP12c and we want to use same objects as in 11g. I copied these file to BIP12c. But not able to browse local folders and open the copied report objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of copying between environments may be causing your problem.

Best practice is to navigate to the xmlpserver (BI Publisher interface) and Download/Upload within there in the source/destination environments, respectively. (BIP uses "Download"/"Upload" rather than "Archive"/"Unarchive" as used in the OBIEE general interface.)

Your URL should look like this:
`http://{Host}:{Port}/xmlpserver/servlet/catalog`

Not this, as in OBIEE interface:
`http://{Host}:{Port}/analytics/saw.dll?catalog`

This is how you get the Download/Upload options in the "More" menu next to your BIP catalog objects.

Alternatively, this could be due to a problem in the Catalog. Use BI Catalog Manager to help you investigate.

Lastly, you need to make sure that you've checked the permissions to the object in both environments.

Comment: Thanks cdabel. I have created a report in OBIEE12c. Where will OBIEE12c store the catalog objects(.xdo, .xdm, .cfg..) by default ?  If it does not store catalog objects in local filesystem, Is there any configuration where in we have to mention that it has to store catalog objects in file system ?

Comment: Chandu, this document may contain the answers to your questions:  https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/biee/BIESG/prescatadmin.htm#BIESG1374  (See sections 16.4.6, and 16.2)
Also, if my answer helped you, could you please mark it correct?

Comment: @Chandu, alternatively, you can log into OBIEE as BI Administrator and change Catalog mode to Admin. This allows you to see the full directory structure of the catalog, including the hidden catalog files (.ATR metadata files). Be careful what you do in Admin mode.